# for multiplayer is server needed to connect players to each other

Tags: networking, architecture, multiplayer

I am trying to understand mechanism of how internet work...i understand dns. But this raise a question that if same is true for multiplayer games as well.

There are two type of multiplayer games that i have seen..Local/Lan and Online.

In online either you connect to a server or one of the people you are with becomes the host.

SO my question is basically can lobby be constructed without needing a server to reffer each player to the pool of players.

If not, than isn't it primitive. Shouldn't there be a way to create unique virtual infinite strings that each client could send request to and tell internet that hey direct all data headed to this address to me too.

Answer (score 0):

The two architectures for multiplayer games that are most common are server based and peer-to-peer.  Any code you could run on a  server, sure - you could run it on a peer to peer basis as well. Simply, put the server code as the peer "server" code.

So in your lobby example, perhaps you could have the client code seek peer-to-peer-based servers versus normal servers. The seeking is the same as in the traditional client-server architecture... just different machines doing the work.

The point is, the client code and server code YOU WRITE has plenty of flexibility to do what you are asking. It just isn't necessarily the easiest way to do these things, so you may not find that people do what you are describing very often. Big games like WoW have plenty of big server machines.

I mean, versus a normal server architecture you could go for something like:

[image]

Comment: ...nvm. I mean even in p2p network there needs to be a server that connects users right?

Answer (score 0):

It boils down to what you mean by "server". If you are asking whether it is necessary that some machine run different code than all the others, in order to produce a multi-player game, my answer to that is no. But then each peer will be likely running some code that has traditional "server" functionality.

Comment: no what i mean is that is it true that there need to be a machine that let other machines Know of others' ip addresses. Or is there a way for computers on internet to connect to each other to form a lobby without  asking some computer who to connect.

Comment: When a lobby is formed, there is some data structure, held somewhere that models that lobby. That data structure can be on one machine, or it can be distributed across many machines. Usually it is easier to put it on one machine. In either case, the machines need to know how to communicate with each other, whether that is P2P or though a central server, or some other configuration.